Ошибка при попытке загрузить ОС с локального TFTP-сервера Debian
Задание. Настроить 2 сервера на Debian 12 в Vmware Workstation, на первом DHCP и TFTP, второй - это клиент. Все настроил, сервы пингуются, но при попытке установить ОС по PXE вылезает error: disk 'tftp,192.168.0.1?' not found.
Очень вероятно что проблемы с папкой /srv/tftp и/или находящимися в ней файлами.
Менял файлы isc-dhcp-server, dhcpd.conf, interfaces, но по всей видимости в правильных местах и не слишком много, потому что IP выделяется и файлы передаются по протоколу – проверял. Также писал файл grub.cfg
На одном из форумов прочитал что у Debian нужно использовать какой-то другой загрузчик, залез – глаза разбежались, и они неизвестного мне формата .deb
https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/2fb63a98d4/
Как устранить ошибку?
Прикладываю скриншоты: файлы и ошибки.
https://imgur.com/a/yQECDf1
Спасибо♥
